# Setting more than one backup DNS server on windows

Tags: windows, dns

I want to add more than one backup DNS server (more than 2 total) on windows, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with the UI. Can I do it through the registry or powershell or something?

Comment: Have you ever heard of a case where two DNS servers failed simultaneously?

Comment: I was trying to do an odd thing with DNS, I understand that two servers are plenty.

Comment: Now I'm perhaps even more curious. What thing? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open your network device's properties, then open the TCP/IPv4 or TCP/IPv6 settings, click "Advanced...", then then select the DNS tab.  There you can add additional DNS servers.